# How to bulk upload synapse notebooks in Synapse Workspace

Tags: powershell, apache-spark, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-synapse

I understand to deploy notebooks from DEV to SIT or PROD we have Synapse Deployment Task in CICD approach but how do I perform bulk upload of .ipynb files ( say 200-300 files at once) in my Dev synapse workspace itself.

I checked this option i.e. [az synapse notebook import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/notebook?view=azure-cli-latest#az_synapse_notebook_import) but looks it works for only single file but doesn't work for multiple files or all files under given folder path..

Comment: Can’t you just pair the workspace with a repo and upload the notebooks to the repo?  Then press refresh in the workspace.  I think that would work.